# Escape apostrophe in a string saved in a cookie

Tags: javascript

I need to save a string value in a cookie, and that string (a person's last name) may contain an apostrophe, like O'Bama.

I tried `lastName.replace(/'/, "\'").toString();` but I get `undefined` in a cookie.

What am I doing wrong, and how should this be done correctly?

Comment: you should use `"\\'"`, `\'` is just escaped `'` which is just `'`.

Comment: You need to double the backslash: `"O'brien".replace(/'/g, "\\'")`. (And I added the `g` modifier, to replace more then one `'` if that should ever occur, and toString is not necessary.)

Comment: Seems like a correct solution... and yet I still get "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `escape()` function in javascript:

```
lastname = escape(lastname);
```

To undo this operation just call `unescape()`...

This will encode all special chars to store them in your cookie.

Some reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the use of `unescape`?

Comment: for unescaping do following: `lastname = unescape(lastname);`. So encoded characters will get decoded.

Comment: Followed your suggestion, should be working just fine... and yet I still get "undefined".

Comment: Check your functions where you store `lastname` in a cookie and then load from it. Encoding won't be the only problem here. Have a look at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: When using jQuery storing and loading will be much easier: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

you only need to escape the string using javascript function:

```
escape()
```

and unescape to get the actual value

```
unescape()
```